# String function: preg-replace

Tags: php, string

I have not achieved result as expected.  Here is what my string and code look like in PHP.

$string in text box

```
"This is 《Carriage Return》
a 《Carriage Return》
test"
```

Then using code in PHP:

```
$cleanstring=preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $string); //(' ' has a space in between)
```

Result came out as:

```
$cleanstring="This is\r\na\r\ntest"
```

But I expected it to be as "This is a test"

Comment: No, something else is wrong https://3v4l.org/1BIgA

Comment: Umm  older version of PHP could be problem of this?   I am using PHP 5.1.1

Comment: 5.1 WTF? That came out 14 years ago.

Comment: No, again https://3v4l.org/1BIgA

Comment: Yeah, I know its old version.  Cant do anything due to employer decision lol.

Comment: AbraCadaver, yes but look at "Output for 7.1.25 - 7.3.5",  does that mean PHP version 7.1.25 thru 7.3.5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the code that works:

```
$cleanstring=trim(preg_replace('/\s{1,}/', ' ', $string));
```